# Problem with a model when selecting

Tags: 3d-view, selection-tools, select

When selecting a couple of objects with a box selection, parts that are outside the box selection are selected and what is inside is not selected. I've tried selecting with other selection tools but it hasn't worked.
All origin points are at the center of each mesh. All similar objects are instantiated. Even if I want to select an object only from the viewport I can't do it while some others can.

Note: It is a CAD file imported as glb into blender & The selection box is in yellow but things are selected outside[image]

Comment: can you share your blend file https://blend-exchange.com

Comment: Are you sure there are no pieces overlapping the box selection? In _Object Mode_ everything is selected that's barely touched - not just those objects where the origins are inside the selection.

Comment: there is no object that is doing overlapping. The size of the selection box is smaller than the yellow square in the image. There are places where I have no problem and everything that is inside the box selection is selected, but other areas like those that do not let me select what is inside and things are selected outside. It is true that there is a "real" object and the others are instances. But the instances can be selected, what cannot be selected are the Arrays

Answer (score 0):

Although I know you said there is no object that is doing the overlapping, I want to demonstrate something because I don't know how experienced you are in Blender (sorry, no offense) or at least this might help other users having similar issues.

Since you stated that these objects come from an imported CAD file and I sometimes have a hard time getting good meshes from CAD files as well, I just wanted to show that there might be something not really visible but nevertheless present there.

[image: hidden geometry]

Comment: I jumped into the edit mode but there was nothing like what you show in the gif. But it's still helpful. The thing is that when in the gif that you show when you select the monkey, the monkey and the cube are selected (because you have a vertex in the monkey's area)
In my case if I select the monkey the cube is selected but not the monkey, and if I select the cube neither the cube nor the monkey is selected.

Comment: Oh, I misread the question obviously... the things in the box are not selected... I mean, the last part (selecting cube selects nothing) could also be something like the cube's _Selectable_ option is disabled and the monkey simply is not inside the selection... but that doesn't explain why selecting the monkey selects the cube. I guess it's hard to find out without having your file.

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution: have you checked if you accidentally changed the *Mode* of the *Box Selection*? By default it is set to *Set a new selection*, but there are also:

- *Extend existing selection*
- *Subtract existing selection*
- *Invert existing selection*
- *Intersect existing selection*

[image: selection mode]

Comment: Cannot post the blender file, sorry for that. Hope you can understand that part ^^". The box selection is by default on Set a new selection.

Comment: I can understand it, but if this is not a general "misbehavior" of your Blender then I've run out of ideas since I cannot reproduce this on my machine with some other model.

Comment: Can instances be the problem?
I have seen that if I select the "instances" they are in red (passive selection) while if I select the first or main one they are selected in orange (actively). The problem I have is in selecting the "original", since things are selected that shouldn't be selected or I am selected correctly